# Why do i get extra records after running query on my mongodb?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I need to extract two columns with names Complaint Id and Date received from my mongodb in R. My csv only has approximately 70k records but when i insert the data and get the two columns above, i get > 400k records. Any idea why this might be happening ?

Using mongolite package, this is the code i used to extract the two columns

```
ids <- as.data.frame(mongoDf$find( fields = '{"Complaint ID":1, "Date received":1, "_id":0}'))
```

Comment: without seeing your data, the code you used to read the csv and then insert it into mongodb it's almost impossible to help you. Try just reading your `csv` into R directly in to a `data.frame` and working on that to establish if there's other issues with your data you've not considered

Answer (score 0):

If your mongodb data contains arrays, it will load this data as lists. You will need to use the $unwind command inside your mongo query when you pass it through a $find or $aggregate query. You may also need to use "flatten" from the jsonlite package.